# HP UX insert text to specific location

Tags: xml, unix, sed, hp-ux

I have a text file in HPUX and I have to insert some xml at a specific location in the file, for example, I have to insert some text after this

```
<Table name="DATA" keys="CONTEXT_ID,USERNAME">  

...my text here
```

in linux i have done this using 'sed' but the same command gives error in HPUX, unable to parse...

please help

In Linux, I have used sed like this

```
sed '\|<table name="MANAGED_USER" keys="CONTEXT_ID,USERNAME">| a \ my text here' file.xml >> file1.xml
```

Comment: What's your sed expression in Linux?

Comment: @Techie: Is something wrong with the copy/pasted Linux sed example? It's certainly not correct as-is. Your problem may stem from the fact that GNU sed is more sophisticated and allows `\n` in places other sed do not. Perhaps you have gsed available on HP-UX?

Comment: Ok, lets make it simple, Can anyone tell me the command to find a phrase in text file and insert some text just after it in HP-UX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for something similar in my shell script.

This article solved my problem:
http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/insert-line-before-or-after-pattern.html

The one I used:

```
    awk '/pattern/{print "your text here"}1' $FILE > /tmp/patawk
    cp /tmp/patawk $FILE 
    rm /tmp/patawk
```